# Element by class vs. Element by id listener for DOMCharacterDataModified

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Currently making a Google Chrome extension, I am trying to get the values (inner HTML) of divs as they update (note, I don't have access to/have control over when they update). For now I'm just printing "status changed" to console every time they update:

```
function state() { console.log("State changed!"); }
var score = document.getElementById("money");
console.log(score);
score.addEventListener('DOMCharacterDataModified', state);
```

The above code actually prints "State changed!" on the given page (http://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/) because the divs are set up so that they have an id attribute: `<div id="money">1</div>`. This is all fine, but when I try to do this on a different page (http://www.musictheory.net/exercises/ear-note) I can't use the same method because their div's are set up like this: `<div class="View ExerciseWebUI-score-text">1117 correct out of 1301 attempts (86%)</div>` i.e. no id attributes, but class attributes. Naturally I have to get score differently, so I tried this:

```
var score = document.getElementsByClassName("View ExerciseWebUI-score-text")[0];
```

When I run the code (note, as a part of the extension it runs at page load), it correctly prints `<div class="View ExerciseWebUI-score-text">1117 correct out of 1301 attempts (86%)</div>` because of `console.log(score);`, but when the inner HTML changes nothing else is printed.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT**:

per Ahmad Ibrahim's comment, I've migrated the DOM event to mutation observers as such:

```
var target = document.getElementById("money");
console.log(target);
var callback = function(mutations, observer) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutationRecord) {
        console.log(mutationRecord.target);
    });
}
var mutationObserver = new WebKitMutationObserver(callback);
var options = { characterData: true, subtree: true };
mutationObserver.observe(target, options);
```

which, once again, works on the first page up top, but working with the second page and changing target to `document.getElementsByClassName("View ExerciseWebUI-score-text")[0];` (once again) prints the node, but does not print any subsequent logs. I'm confident that this has something to do with the assignment of the `target` variable. Any suggestions?

Comment: FYI, DOM Events are now deprecated, consider using DOM MutationObservers instead.

Comment: could you link me to a resource? or explain briefly what that even means...

Comment: check this one. http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers